# Google Sheets Script Replace Cells in a Column, of a certain value, with a link

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's say I have a sheet, and column B is all numbers. I want to replace all instances of 0 in that column with a link. So for example:

413
872
0
623

Becomes...

413
872
www.google.com
623

Comment: Please provide the code of your current attempt, and any errors if received. We do not know what you've tried, if you have at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is: (1) get a [sheet object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet); (2) get a [range object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range); (3) get the values from that range; (4) loop over them, keeping in mind that this is a *double* array, with two indices; (5) set the new values back into the range.

```
function replace() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("B:B");
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] === 0) {
      values[i][0] = 'www.google.com';
    }
  }
  range.setValues(values);
}
```